# Remove string of characters from filename using Applescript or Linux

Tags: linux, pdf, ms-word, applescript, filenames

I am converting several word documents to pdfs. The input file names are like this "CM_Genetics_in_OBGYN_docx" while the output file names are like this "job_10-Microsoft_Word_-_CM_Genetics_in_OBGYN_docx.pdf" I want to delete "job_10-Microsoft_Word_-_" and "_docx" and only have the pdf file name left "CM_Genetics_in_OBGYN.pdf". I would really like to end up with "CM Genetics in OBGYN.pdf" but "CM_Genetics_in_OBGYN.pdf" would be acceptable if that last part makes it too complicated. I have some experience with applescript and linux commands but can't nail this down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
for fn in job_*.pdf; do
    newname=${fn#job_??-*-_}
    newname=${newname/_docx}
    newname=${newname//_/ }
    echo "mv '$fn' '$newname'"
done
```

This will print `mv` commands ready execute, but without renaming anything. To execute the rename, simply pipe the output to `sh`.

The `echo` is useful to test everything safely. Make sure to check on the strangest pattern you can find to cover all corner cases. If everything looks good, change the `echo` to do the real action you want to perform instead, for example:

```
for fn in job_*.pdf; do
    newname=${fn#job_??-*-_}
    newname=${newname/_docx}
    newname=${newname//_/ }
    mv "$fn" "/some/other/dir/$newname"
done
```

Comment: This is the result I get in the terminal <mv 'job_10-Microsoft_Word_-_CM_Genetics_in_OBGYN_docx.pdf' 'CM Genetics in OBGYN.pdf'> which looks like what I want. Thanks a lot! Also I'm trying to add this into a workflow in automator where I have it set up to dispense the items one at a time and I want this step to rename the item and return it the same folder as it was taken from in the workflow. Exactly how do I get it to do that. If the command just ended and no redirection was given the file would return to where it came, right? I couldn't get it to do that though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should be able to do that by tweaking that last `echo` line in the loop. (I made a small update to my post in case it might help with your next step.)